# Is there a way to determine whether there is no remaining data when reading from SerialPort in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to read data from SerialPort and what I'm now trying to do is to poll the SerialPort every 100ms and see if it contains any remaining data.

```
    public static async Task<string> ReadRemaining(SerialPort port)
    {
        int prevBytesToRead = 0;
        await Task.Delay(100);
        while (prevBytesToRead != port.BytesToRead || port.BytesToRead == 0)
        {
            prevBytesToRead = port.BytesToRead;
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
        return port.ReadExisting();
    }
```

I feel this is very inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already are using the `BytesToRead` property, which is not really the best approach<sup>1</sup>, but I guess it is working for you.

You appear to be asking for a prediction of the future, you're asking about data that hasn't yet been sent from the other device.  There's no way for the serial port to know that.  Perhaps based on your application protocol, the other device tells you when it is done sending (end of message marker) or perhaps told you how long the message would be.

You have to figure out how to rephrase the question so it doesn't require prophesying the future.

---

<sup>1</sup>The clean way to use serial ports and C# async is to call `port.BaseStream.ReadAsync`.  Make sure the timeouts are set properly.  Under Win32 timeouts you can detect gaps in the stream which often correspond to message boundaries, sadly .NET SerialPort doesn't allow that.  But you still can find a better value for the `ReadTimeout` property than the default.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I've read your blog on how we really should use port.BaseStream.ReadAsync for COM I/O but I cannot quite figure out a good example for reading the stream "till there is no input after some time intervals". Can you give me an example?

Comment: @derekh: That behavior is provided by `ReadIntervalTimeout` in the `COMMTIMEOUTS` structure... but .NET `SerialStream.ReadTimeout` property won't set that to any value except `INFINITE`.  And I can't see a way to get the handle in order to p/invoke `SetCommTimeouts`.  So you'll have to do per-call read timeouts.

Comment: OK. I think I can figure that out now. :) Thanks Ben!